# Circuit Golf: Puzzle page for Electrical Engineers?

Tags: discussion, area51

So I find the page [Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) quite interesting and fun. I'm in IT but also like and know some EE stuff. I'm just wondering, how many people here would like a "Circuit Golf" page, one where EE people solve puzzles using (simple) circuits.

The name doesn't have to be "Circuit Golf". Just a page for EE puzzlez.

Comment: Not really the place to discuss. Go to "Area 51" or maybe the chat.

Comment: I'm not planning to actually make the page. The idea was just on impulse and I'd just like some thought on it.

Comment: If it involves Karnaugh maps, I'm out of here. They are kind of similar to Sudoku though...

Answer (score 7):

We don't need a separate site for that. We get plenty of circuit design "puzzles" in the normal course of business. Feel free to jump in. We also get lots of reverse-engineering questions, which are a kind of puzzle.

The problem is that electrical engineering is much "fuzzier" than software programming. In the latter, you can clearly tell whether or not you produced the desired output. In EE, you can meet the requirements to a greater or lesser degree, depending on which corners you cut. This also makes the requirements harder to write down in the first place.

Comment: You either meet requirements or you don't.  If you can't tell if you do, you're insufficiently specced (i.e., "harder to write down...")

Answer (score 0):

I assume you relate to genuine golfing (achieving something in an unusual way or with the smallest amount of components). In contrast to reverse engineering, analysis etc.

---

This request could be made for other fields as well: engineering, chemistry, cooking, gardening, ...

I don't think having golfing sites for all of them is the right way. Either one shall step in and start a *generic* golfing site² on Area 51 or it shall be allowed to ask on the related existing site (EE.SE in this case).

² = Assuming converting Codegolf.SE to a generic site is not feasible (this would probably better).

We might consider defining differentiated rules on such a puzzle and adding a tag.